# Función R hdr.den(), problema con intervalos en el eje x

Tags: r, rstudio, axis

Tengo un problema con la función hdr.den, no me es posible modificar los intervalos del eje x, y sólo puedo pintar el gráfico con los intervalos por defecto. Mi código es:

```
library(hdrcde)
dades <- data.frame(via = c("A-2", "A-2", "A-2"), pk = c(450, 450.2, 451), valor = c(3, 1, 2))
dens <- density(dades$pk, bw = 0.1)
nBreaks = 10
xaxpi <- c(trunc(min(dades$pk)), trunc(max(dades$pk)), nBreaks)

hdr <- hdr.den(round(dades$pk, 1), den = dens,
           xaxp = xaxpi, cex.axis = 0.6, las = 2,
           main = paste("Concentraciones relativas"))
```

Por mucho que varíe la variable nBreaks, los ejes de la función no me cambian:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También he intentado quitar completamente las divisiones del eje x, poniendo el parámetro:

```
xaxp = "n"
```

Pero esto tampoco ha funcionado.

Por último, si añado los ejes manualmente de esta forma:

```
axis(side= 1, xaxp=xaxpi)
```

Entonces se superponen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería si alguien supiera cómo resolverlo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el formato no va ser **png** con fondo transparente se podría obtener el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea central es visualizar como **R** plotea los gráficos. Para tal fin, **R** toma como marco de referencia, la configuración de nuestro entorno de **desarrollo**, esto es muy similar a otros programas de diseño gráfico como **Adobe Illustrator**, **Sketch**, entre otros.

Esto se logra como bien han señalado en otras respuesta mediante los [parámetros gráficos -  par](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.3/topics/par), es decir **R** efectuará los lienzos conforme estén definidos estos parámetros.

Lo señalado en el párrafo anterior es similar a **Photoshop** por ejemplo, porque permite flexibilidad y trabajar los lienzos como capas, es decir una capa sobre otra capa, hasta obtener el resultado que se requiere.

Por tanto, el código que genera el gráfico arriba señalado, sería el siguiente:

```
library(hdrcde)
dades <- data.frame(via = c("A-2", "A-2", "A-2"),
                    pk = c(450, 450.2, 451),
                    valor = c(3, 1, 2))

dens <- density(dades$pk, bw = 0.1)

# En este caso se establecen 3 marcadores (length.out) para mostrar
# las partes altas y bajas de la gráfica
# esto no formará parte del primer lienzo
xaxpi <- round(seq(min(dades$pk)+0.1, 
                   max(dades$pk),
                   length.out = 3),1)

# o tambien: xaxpi <- c(450.1,450.6,451.0)

# se hace necesario establecer las separaciones de la densidad
# porque en el primera capa no seran dibujados
# también max(dens$y) podría ser cambiado por 1.5 o el
# valor que se ajuste a vuestras necesidades
yaxpi <- round(seq(0, max(dens$y), length.out = 4),1)

# antes de hacer el lienzo se le dice a R a través de "par"
# que la longitud de los marcadores es cero
# y que su color como el de sus valores es blanco
par(tck=0, col.axis="white", col.ticks="white")

# Se realiza el lienzo
hdr <- hdr.den(round(dades$pk, 1), den = dens,
               main = paste("Concentraciones relativas"))

# se reestablece el alto de los marcadores
par(tck=-0.05) 

# efectua una nueva capa sobre el lienzo previamente ploteado
axis(1, at=xaxpi ,col.axis="black", col.ticks="black", cex.axis=0.7, las=2)
axis(2, at=yaxpi ,col.axis="black", col.ticks="black", cex.axis=0.7)
```

Adicionalmente como se está usando el `par` si se quiere que vuelva a sus valores por defecto, se puede emplear:

```
dev.off()
```

En este post [Reset par to the default values at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789982/reset-par-to-the-default-values-at-startup) se detalla más al respecto.

Finalmente `yaxpi` también puede ser personalizado hasta que sea como máximo `1.5` y no `1.6`.

Answer (score 2):

Lamentablemente mirando el código de `hdr.den` veo que dibuja los `breaks` a su manera y no hay forma de indicarle que lo haga de otra forma, o que de última, no los dibuje. También, los parámetros adicionales que le pasas, por alguna razón no le están llegando a la función `plot()` por lo que son inútiles, hablo de `cex.axis = 0.6` y `las = 2`.

El otro problema que tienes es que estás definiendo mal los `breaks`, esto: `c(trunc(min(dades$pk)), trunc(max(dades$pk)), nBreaks)` crea un vector de tres valores, imagino que en realidad quieres algo así:

```
nBreaks = 10
xaxpi <- round(seq(min(dades$pk), 
                   max(dades$pk), 
                   length.out = nBreaks),1)

xaxpi
[1] 450.0 450.1 450.2 450.3 450.4 450.6 450.7 450.8 450.9 451.0
```

Con respecto al gráfico, podrías sobrescribir los `breaks`, no es lo más elegante pero es sencillo y funciona, lo que sí es fundamental la orientación de estos para que no se superpongan:

```
par(las=2)
hdr <- hdr.den(round(dades$pk, 1), 
               den = dens,
               main = paste("Concentraciones relativas"))
axis(side = 1, at = xaxpi)
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

> La solución de @PatricioMoracho es más sencilla.

Revisando el código de `hdr.den()` y encontré que los argumentos estándar para ejes (que permitirían usar `xaxp=`) están suprimidos, por eso las modificaciones que pasas a los ejes no funcionan. Es decir, la función captura `...` y pasa los argumentos bien (por eso funciona `main=`), pero esos ejes se suprimen.

La función dibuja los ejes pasando un `axis(2, ...)`, ahí debería estar incluido el argumento `xaxp = xaxpi`, pero no hay manera de pasar ese argumento en la función como tal está. La opción obvia sería modificar levemente la función original para agregar los argumento en el lugar correcto. Con eso se logra hacer el gráfico que quieres, pero se "rompe" la función, ya que al pasarla al entorno global pierde una la referencia a una función llamada dentro. Entonces hay que modificar a la función pero dentro de su propio entorno.

La única alternativa que encontré para eso es un hack en el peor sentido de la palabra. Consiste en editar la función `hdr.den()` usando un `trace()` para que no salga de su entorno original.

Con `hdrcde` cargada introduces

```
trace("hdr.den", edit = T)
```

Esto va a abrir una ventana con el código de la función. Busca la línea 26, que debería tener el código:

```
axis(1)
```

Y lo reemplazas por

```
axis(1, xaxp = xaxpi, las = 2)
```

y luego `Save` en el botón correspondiente. Así con tu código original debería funcionar, ya que tendrías `xaxpi` en el entorno global.

> Cada vez que reinicies `R` la función vuelve a la original. Creo que eso es bueno para evitar problemas silenciosos derivados de la modificación. No es para nada buena práctica modificar una función "al vuelo", pero a veces no hay alternativa.

Este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]